Not able to add a new property to the result array of an apex call
I am trying to add a new property called showDeleteButton to the result array that was returned as part of an apex call. Here I have code after what is pasted below, but for some reason when I add the result.forEach line, the code after wont execute.
        getLaborProductsByPartCategoryAndEquipmentType({ partCategories: partCategories, equipmentType: this.veteranequipmenttype })
            .then(result => {
                console.log('Result before modification:', JSON.stringify(result));
                result.forEach(item => {
                    item.showDeleteButton = false; 
                });
                console.log('Result after modification:', JSON.stringify(result));

                this.laborProducts = result; //This array will just hold the labor products.}


Results from wire or imerative apex calls are immutable (so client side caches for results can easily be maintained). As per the documentation:

Assume that Apex methods provision immutable data, even if it's possible to mutate the data today. It's a best practice to treat all data that a component receives as immutable. To mutate the data, make a shallow copy of the objects you want to mutate. It’s important to understand this concept when working with data.

And, BTW, "even if it's possible ... today" is out of date. Your code is likely suffering a runtime exception, hence the code "not executing".
Shallow copying the array is not enough. You need a copy of the objects that you want to mutate, so not the array, but the objects in the array. Essentially you must copy down to the level in the object structure where you want to mutate.

I create a shallow copy of the result this.laborProducts = [...result]; then I added the new property to each item on the results array                         this.laborProducts.forEach(record => {                             record.showDeleteButton = false;                         });. I am still getting an error.

You actually need to shallow copy all the objects in the array itself since you want to add a property to these objects.

Thanks @Phil W.
